# Are there issues with building constraints inside willRotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: ios

When I get a rotation notice via willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, I remove my current constraints and build new ones right there in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation routine .

Everything seems to work just fine.   But I have a niggling memory that I'd read that this is a bad practice.

Can anyone cite specific issues or concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, since there have been no answers or suggestions, that the answer is no one knows of any issues.  So, let's accept that a move on.